# How to remove similar list from a list. how to remove duplicates from the list

Tags: python

```
index=[[25, 0], [25, 1], [25, 0], [25, 4], [25, 1], [25, 4], [56, 2], [56, 3]]
for x in range(0,len(index)):
    for y in range(x+1,len(index)):
        if index[x][-1]==index[y][-1]:
            index.remove(index[y])
print(index)
```

Got the following error:

```
 if index[x][-1]==index[y][-1]: IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Explain what are you trying to do

Comment: it would be easier if you convert these nested `lists` into a `tuple` and then use `set`.

Comment: Now is a good time to learn the practices of basic debugging.  Your post should include your trace of `x, y,` and `index` on each loop iteration, especially just before the point of failure.  You also should not ask how to remove duplicates, as that is a straightforward lookup.  Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the
[intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  
You haven't yet done the expected research.

Comment: `newlist = [x for i,x in enumerate(mylist) if x not in mylist[:i]]` will do the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looping over a list and deleting the same list simultaneously .. It ran out of index with which the loop was started. Make a copy of list and then run over it.

Slightly edited code.

```py
index=[[25, 0], [25, 1], [25, 0], [25, 4], [25, 1], [25, 4], [56, 2], [56, 3]]
index_for_loop = index.copy()
for x in range(0,len(index_for_loop)):
    for y in range(x+1,len(index_for_loop)):
        if index_for_loop[x]==index_for_loop[y]:
            index.remove(index_for_loop[y])
print(index)
```

Gives output

```py
[[25, 0], [25, 1], [25, 4], [56, 2], [56, 3]]
```

Answer (score 1):

One-liner:

```
index = list(map(list, (set(tuple(a) for a in index))))
```

gives

```
[[25, 4], [25, 0], [56, 3], [56, 2], [25, 1]]
```

Lists are unhashable in Python, hence you need to convert them to `tuple` first.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following

```
index = [[25, 0], [25, 1], [25, 0], [25, 4], [25, 1], [25, 4], [56, 2], [56, 3]]

lst = []

for i in range(len(index)):
    if index[i] not in lst:
        lst += [index[i]]

print(lst)
>>> [[25, 0], [25, 1], [25, 4], [56, 2], [56, 3]]
```